# List jax-rs service beans

Tags: java, spring, web-services, cxf, jax-rs

I have a jax-rs servlet configured with spring. In my beans.xml, I have a list of jax-rs beans:

```
<jaxrs:server id="salesRest" address="/">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <bean id="usersWS" class="co.my.package.UsersImpl" />
        <bean id="authenticationWS" class="co.my.package.AuthenticationImpl" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    ...
<jaxrs:server>
```

What I want is to be able to get a list of these beans programmatically, e.g. from the Application Context. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through the jax-rs jar, I found some code in JaxRsInInterceptor.class that pointed me in the right direction: essentially you can get the JaxRsServerFactoryBean from the application context (or inject it), and then:

```
    List<ClassResourceInfo> cris = jaxrsServerFactoryBean.getServiceFactory().getClassResourceInfo();
```

Gives you a list of all service beans.